# Calling MS Access VBA function in a module from web page in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, vba, function, ms-access

In Access 2007 database, I have a custom function called "IsIn" in Module1 that looks like this:

@TimWilliams: you have nailed the proble, I think.  I think, then, I'll need to recode it in .Net which is fine, but then I'm not sure how to use the function in .Net and in SQL like that - do you have an example?  Here's the whole function (I had shortened it for brevity):

```
Public Function IsIn(Arr1 As Variant, Arr2 As Variant) As Boolean

  Dim comp1() As String
  Dim comp2() As String
  comp1() = Split(Arr1, " ")
  comp2() = Split(Arr2, " ")

  Dim x, y As Long
  For x = LBound(comp1) To UBound(comp1)
    For y = LBound(comp2) To UBound(comp2)
        If comp1(x) = comp2(y) Then
            IsIn = True
        End If
    Next y
  Next x

End Function
```

I use it in a SQL query as such:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM TableA AS A, TableB AS B
WHERE IsIn(A.Field1,B.Field1)=True
```

This works fine as a query in Access.

But in my .aspx page, when I execute the query, it fails.  I know the function is causing the problem, because the query works if I comment out just that line (the WHERE) clause.  When the SQL executes, it executes successfully, but returns no rows.

My SQL code is as follows, and works everywhere else in my website just fine - and works if the function line in the SQL is commented out:

`rstResult = ExecQuery(SQL)`,  where SQL is the SQL from above

```
Public Function ExecQuery(ByVal SQL_Query As String)

   Try
        OpenDB
        Dim OleDbCmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL_Query,conn)
        Dim OleDbAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(OleDbCmd)
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        OleDbAdapter.Fill(DT)
        CloseDB

        OleDbAdapter.Dispose()
        OleDbCmd.Dispose()

        Return DT

    Catch ex as Exception
        LogSQLError(ex,"methodName")
    End Try

End Function
```

Any help is appreciated - thanks

Comment: You cannot use a custom function in SQL when running it from outside of the actual Access application.  See for example http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/124351-custom-function-vba-access-stored-query-called-asp-net   Is that your *actual* function?

Comment: This is asp.net, not classic asp

Comment: @John, yes it is asp.net.@TimWilliams: you have nailed the problem, I think.  I had shortened the function in the original question for brevity - I'm adding the entire function to the original question, so you can see the whole thing.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Thanks for the link you provided, I think I have a potential solution that is working.  Essentially, I've created a similar IsIn function in code-behind, I select all the data into a DataTable, process that DataTable using the function, and utilize the data in the resulting DataTable.  I think this is what you may have been pointing me to.  Thanks, again.